# Проблема с HTML5 video, клавиша пробел

Tags: javascript, html5, видео

Собственно, я делаю кастомизированный HTML5 плеер под себя.Убрал стандартную контроль панель и заменил своей(обрамил CSS`ом, сделал функциональность на JS).Но вот проблема, почему-то пробел, по моим меркам остался стандартный и мешает мне(я его вообще не использую и не декларирую).Когда кликаю на любую визуальную кнопку мышью, а потом допустим нажимаю пробел, то он триггерит любую функцию, любой кнопки(последней нажатой), будь то Mute, Play, Fullscreen и т.д.Не пойму в чем проблема.Его вообще не должно быть и он не должен работать.

Comment: Не думаю, что проблема в коде, похоже на то, что я чего то не знаю, либо неправильно делаю.Пожалуйста, подскажите.

Comment: А вы не видели что так происходит почти с любым плеером на разных сайтах, когда все стандартные кнопки все ровно заменены

Comment: Как это обойти или надписать, вы не знаете??Нет, не замечал.

Comment: Не могу сходу сказать, но посмотрите например в `youtube`. Пробел реагирует так же как вы сейчас в вопросе описали.